# Creating a new node with given value in a generic linked list in C with void pointers

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, malloc, void

I'm writing a library for generic linked lists in C using `void` pointers. This is my node:

```
typedef struct List {
    void* data;
    struct List* next;
} List;
```

and this is the function I use to create a new node with given data:

```
List* newNode (void* data) {
    List* newNode = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (newNode) {
        newNode->data = malloc(sizeof(data));
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

I have no idea how to substitute the `newNode->data = data` line in order to make the assignment work. I tried using `memcpy(newNode->data, data, sizeof(data))` but it seems like it only works with strings. Also, I'm not sure about evaluating `sizeof(data)` inside the function since I'm afraid it wouldn't return the correct value.

What would be the correct way of proceeding to copy the new data inside the `data` field of the new node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide if you want your list to store pointers to values or if you want to store values themselves.

If you want to store *only* pointers and let the user of your library care about memory allocation of elements, then:

```
List* newNode (void* data) {
    List* newNode = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (newNode) {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

is fine. If you want to store values, you have to pass the size of the object to your function to know how much to allocate and copy:

```
List* newNode(void* data, size_t datasize) {
    List* newNode = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (newNode) {
        newNode->data = malloc(datasize);
        if (!newNode->data) {
             free(newNode);
             return NULL;
        }
        memcpy(newNode->data, data, datasize);
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    return newNode;
}
int main() {
    int a;
    List *l = newNode(&a, sizeof(a));
}
```

> I'm not sure about evaluating sizeof(data) inside the function since I'm afraid it wouldn't return the correct value.

`data` is a `void*`, so `sizeof(data)` gives you `sizeof(void*)` - size of a `void*` pointer.

---

> how can we do that since void* pointer can't be de-referenced?

Create a function that prints one element and apply it on each list element. In pseudocode:

```
void list_apply_foreach(list *t,
      void (*apply)(void *elem, void *cookie), void *cookie) {
   for (iterate over list in t) {
      apply(i->data, cookie);
   }
}

void print_int(void *elem, void *cookie) {
    printf("%d ", *(int*)elem);
}

int main() {
     list *l = list_make_list_of_ints(1, 2, 3, 4);
     list_apply_foreach(l, print_int);
}
```

Comment: In case we want to print the List(not the address but the values pointed by data), how can we  do that since void* pointer can't be de-referenced?

Comment: To be generic, pass a function pointer that prints one element to a function that applies that function on each list element.

Comment: @soubhiksen Thank you, it also looks like I was trying to print the list using the wrong function, that is why the contents of the list weren't being displayed correctly and it looked like there was some memory issue hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

I’m working on code that does this exact thing as an academic exercise to flex my old data structures muscles (and because I'm bored to tears with what I'm supposed to be working on).  It's a doubly-linked list of key-value pairs (for lists of single items like integers or floats or strings, we only use the key and leave the data item empty), where keys and values can be pretty much anything.

I do this by liberally using `void *` and dependency injection.

Before we go any further, please note that the code below is very much a work in progress - don't get too hung up on any inconsistencies or iffy-looking practice.

The way I’ve set it up is I attach a bunch of callbacks to the list object to handle copying, assignment, and comparisons:

```
struct glist {
  Node *head;       // Node is opaque - I provide an API to create
  Node *tail;       // and manipulate Node objects. 
  size_t count;

  int   (*cmp) ( const void *, const void * ); // comparison for ordering
  void *(*kcpy)( const void * );               // copy key 
  void *(*dcpy)( const void * );               // copy data
  void  (*kdst)( const void * );               // destroy key
  void  (*ddst)( const void * );               // destroy data
};
```

then on inserts, searches, deletions, etc., I rely on those callbacks to know how to deal with the actual data.

On an insert, I pass the `*cpy` callbacks to the node creation function, then use the `cmp` callback to insert the node in order:

```
bool glist_insert( GList *l, const void *key, const void *data )
{
  assert( l != NULL && key != NULL );

  Node *newNode = node_create( key, data, l->kcpy, l->dcpy );
  if ( !newNode )
    return false;

  Node *cur = glist_begin( l );
  if ( node_next( cur ) != glist_end( l ) )
  {
    while ( node_next( cur ) != glist_end( l ) && l->cmp( node_key( newNode ), node_key( node_next( cur ) ) ) >= 0 )
      cur = node_next( cur );
  }

  node_insert_after( cur, newNode );
  l->count++;
  return true;
}
```

And then in the node creation function, the callbacks know how to allocate and copy the key and data values:

```
Node *node_create( const void *key, const void *data, void *(*kcpy)( const void * ), void *(*dcpy)( const void * ) )
{
  assert( key != NULL && kcpy != NULL );
  Node *n = calloc( 1, sizeof *n );
  if ( n )
  {
    n->key = kcpy( key );
    if ( !n->key )
    {
      free( n );
      n = NULL;
    }
    else if ( data && dcpy )
    {
      n->data = dcpy( data );
      if ( !n->data )
      {
        free( n->key );
        free( n );
        n = NULL;
      }
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

Then for a list of integers, I just need to create callbacks for allocating `int`s:

```
void *int_cpy( const void *data )
{
  assert( data != NULL );

  const int *d = data;

  int *buf = malloc( sizeof *buf );
  if ( buf )
    *buf = *d;

  return buf;
}
```

and comparing them:

```
/**
 * Sorts in ascending order
 */
int int_cmp_asc( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
  assert( lhs != NULL && rhs != NULL );

  const int *l = lhs;
  const int *r = rhs;

  if ( *l < *r ) return -1;
  else if ( *l > *r ) return 1;
  
  return 0;
}

/**
 * Sorts in descending order
 */
int int_cmp_dsc( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
  assert( lhs != NULL && rhs != NULL );

  const int *l = lhs;
  const int *r = rhs;

  if ( *l < *r ) return 1;
  else if ( *l > *r ) return -1;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Then I create a lightweight, type-aware interface that wraps the generic interface:

```
bool ilist_insert( GList *l, int data )
{
  return glist_insert( l, &data, NULL );
}
```

Similarly, for displaying the contents of a list, I rely on a callback to format the data for display:

```
/**
 * Display list contents, formatted.  
 * 
 * My list type supports bidirectional traversal with functions like
 *
 *    list_begin  - begin at the head of the list
 *    list_rbegin - begin at the tail of the list
 *    list_end    - end at the tail of the list
 *    list_rend   - end at the head of the list
 *    node_next   - get the node following the current node
 *    node_rnext  - get the node preceding the current node
 *
 * So to display in either order, I call this function with either
 * list_begin, list_end, and node_next, or list_rbegin, list_rend,
 * and node_rnext.
 */
void glist_display( FILE *stream, GList *l, Node *(*start)( GList * ), Node *(*end)( GList * ), Node *(*iter)( Node * ), char *delim, char *(*fmt)( Node *n, char *tgt, size_t tgtSize ) )
{
  assert( stream != NULL && l != NULL );

  /**
   * I need a better way to determine the buffer size, but that's
   * for a later version.
   */
  char dbuf[1024];

  Node *cur = start( l );
  cur = iter( cur );
  if ( cur == end( l ) )
  {
    fputs( "[nil]", stream );
    return;
  }

  char *sep = "";
  do
  {
    fprintf( stream, "%s%s", sep, fmt( cur, dbuf, sizeof dbuf ) );
    cur = iter( cur );
    sep = delim;
  } while( cur != end( l ) );
}

/**
 * Formatter for int objects.  Caller must supply the target
 * buffer.
 */
char *int_fmt( Node *n, char *tgt, size_t tgtSize )
{
  assert( n != NULL && tgt != NULL && tgtSize > 12 );

  sprintf( tgt, "%d", *(int *) node_key( n ) );
  return tgt;
}
```

and all of this gets called as

```
glist_display( stdout, list, glist_begin, glist_end, node_next, ", ", int_fmt );
```

Example with `int` (ascending and descending order):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "IList.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  /**
   * ilist_create "overloads" glist_create, passing "default"
   * copy and destroy callbacks - the only thing we specify here
   * is the comparison callback.
   */
  GList *asc = ilist_create( int_cmp_asc );
  GList *dsc = ilist_create( int_cmp_dsc );

  size_t limit = 10;

  if ( argc > 1 )
  {
    limit = strtoul( argv[1], NULL, 0 );
  }

  for( size_t i = 0; i < limit; i++ )
  {
    int r = rand() % 100;

    ilist_insert( asc, r );
    ilist_insert( dsc, r );
  }
  glist_display( stdout, asc, glist_begin, glist_end, node_next, ", ", int_fmt );
  putc( '\n', stdout );

  glist_display( stdout, dsc, glist_begin, glist_end, node_next, ", ", int_fmt );
  putc( '\n', stdout );

  glist_destroy( asc );
  return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
$ ./list_test_int
7, 9, 23, 30, 44, 49, 58, 72, 73, 78
78, 73, 72, 58, 49, 44, 30, 23, 9, 7
```

Here's an example that creates a list of movies - the key is the title and release year, the data is the director, rating, and runtime:

```
struct movie_key {
  char *title;
  int year;
};

struct movie_data {
  char *director;
  char rating[6];
  char *runtime;
};

...

bool movie_insert( GList *l, const struct movie_key key, const struct movie_data data )
{
  return glist_insert( l, &key, &data );
}

...

int main( void )
{
  GList *l = glist_create( movie_kcpy, movie_dcpy, movie_kcmp, movie_kdst, movie_ddst );

  FILE *f = fopen( "movies.dat", "r" );
  if ( f )
  {
    struct movie_key key = { NULL, 0 };
    struct movie_data data = { NULL, "", NULL };

    while( getNextMovie( f, &key, &data ) )
      movie_insert( l, key, data );
    fclose( f );
  }

  glist_display( stdout, l, glist_begin, glist_end, node_next, "\n", movie_fmt );
  fputc( '\n', stdout );
  glist_destroy( l );

  return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
$ ./movies 
"Cape Fear" (1962) Rated NR; Directed by J. Lee Thompson; Run time 1h 46min
"Cape Fear" (1991) Rated R; Directed by Martin Scorsese; Run time 2h 8min
"Gone with the Wind" (1939) Rated G; Directed by Victor Fleming, George Cukor, Sam Wood; Run time 3h 58min
"Jaws" (1975) Rated PG; Directed by Steven Spielberg; Run time 2h 4min
"Phantom of the Paradise" (1974) Rated PG; Directed by Brian DePalma; Run time 1h 31min
"The Adventures of Buckaroo Banzai Across the 8th Dimension" (1984) Rated PG; Directed by W.D. Richter; Run time 1h 43min
"The Lord of the Rings" (1978) Rated PG; Directed by Ralph Bakshi; Run time 2h 12min
"The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring" (2001) Rated PG-13; Directed by Peter Jackson; Run time 2h 58min
"The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King" (2003) Rated PG-13; Directed by Peter Jackson; Run time 3h 21min
"The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers" (2002) Rated PG-13; Directed by Peter Jackson; Run time 2h 59min
```

Same base list code for both, just with lightweight wrappers and a lot of dependency injection.

Here's the `Node` interface (again, this is a work in progress, I know there are inconsistencies here):

```
#ifndef GNODE_H
#define GNODE_H

#include <stdbool.h>

/**
 * Implementation of Node type is hidden
 */
typedef struct node Node;

Node *node_create( const void *key, const void *data, void *(*kcpy)( const void * ), void *(*dcpy)( const void * ) );
void node_destroy( Node *n, void (*kdst)( const void * ), void (*ddst)( const void * ) );
void node_insert_after( Node *n, Node *newNode );
void node_insert_before( Node *n, Node *newNode );
bool node_remove( Node *n );
 
/**
 * Iterators
 */
Node *node_next( Node *n );
Node *node_rnext( Node *n );

/**
 * Get the value attached to the node
 */
void *node_key( Node *n );
void *node_data( Node *n );
void node_set_data( Node *n, const void * data, void (*dst)( const void * ), void *(*cpy)( const void * ) );
void node_clear_data( Node *n, void (*dst)( const void * ) );

#endif
```

And the `GList` interface:

```
#ifndef GLIST_H
#define GLIST_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GNode.h"

/**
 * Generic doubly-linked list type.  Only the name is exposed, not the implementation.
 */
typedef struct glist GList;

GList *glist_create( void *(*kcpy)( const void * ), 
                   void *(*dcpy)( const void * ), 
                   int  (*cmp)( const void *, const void * ), 
                   void (*kdst)( const void * ), 
                   void (*ddst)( const void * ) );

void glist_destroy( GList *l );

/**
 * Insert at the beginning of the list
 */
bool glist_insert( GList *l, const void *key, const void *data );

/**
 * Insert at the end of the list
 */
bool glist_rinsert( GList *l, const void *key, const void *data );
bool glist_remove( GList *l, const void *key );

/**
 * Search from the beginning of the list
 */
Node *glist_find( GList *l, const void *key );

/**
 * Search from the end of the list
 */
Node *glist_rfind( GList *l, const void *key );

void glist_display( FILE *stream, GList *l, Node *(*begin)( GList * ), Node *(*end)( GList * ), Node *(*iter)( Node * ), char *delim, char *(*fmt)( Node *n, char *tgt, size_t tgtSize ) );
void glist_dump( FILE *stream, GList *l );

Node *glist_begin( GList *l );
Node *glist_end( GList *l ); 
Node *glist_rbegin( GList *l );
Node *glist_rend( GList *l ); 

size_t glist_size( GList *l );

#endif
```

Comment: Awesome! This is proof that simple data structures can be made arbitrarily complex and suitable for any use.

Comment: @outsidethecave: Yeah, but there's a cost - with all those calls and callbacks and dynamic allocation, this isn't the most performant code.  And you lose any hint of type safety with all those `void *`s - there's no way for the compiler to yell at you if you install incompatible callbacks.  But, as an exercise in abstraction, it's pretty illustrative.